# Rails's Rake task takes exceptionally long to execute?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I speed up Ruby/Rake task](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8545459/how-can-i-speed-up-ruby-rake-task)

Within my Rails application, any Rake task I perform takes an exceptionally long to execute.  What may be the cause of this and how might I achieve a speedup?

Comment: What action? What rails version? What OS are you using? How large is your project?

Comment: @Paul which rake task you are running

Comment: any rake task, any rails version, any os, seems to be indiffrent to project size. The task is executed fast, but preparations are too long.

Comment: @Paul - OK then, what Ruby version? (and what do you mean about *any* OS - which have you tried it on?) For example, I'm stuck using Ruby 1.8 and starting Rake on my (corporate/virus-protected/security-enladened) Windows desktop takes a minute and a half at a minimum. But on the Linux server, it's basically instantaneous (probably a second or two, really).